# htaccess. Некорректный редирект

Tags: php, .htaccess

Происходит странная переадресация. Делаю счетчик на основе htaccess и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
При запрашивании главной страницы все работает, да и в любой папке все работает корректно, но при открытии папки (именно папки, если через sub-admin/index.php, то работает) sub-admin, происходит редирект на http://localhost/C:/OSPanel/domains/localhost/php/counter.php?f=
Да и откуда он мог взятся я поменял нахождение файла counter.php, он был в директории php, а теперь просто в корне сайта.
Вот .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !count=ok
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sub-admin
#RewriteRule ^.*$ php/counter.php
RewriteRule . counter.php
```

Не понимаю в чем дело...
Сам counter.php прост:

```
<?php
die($_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]."?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо OpenServer, как-то кэширует файлы. Поменял директорию сайта на другую - все заработало...